# Fluid full screen width banner with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, banner

I want to create a banner like this:
http://themeforest.net/item/overgrowth-retina-responsive-multipurpose-theme/full_screen_preview/4896083

this banner has an image which has width of 1920px. but when the the page is zoomed out, the banner is still full page width and and nothing is cropped. the height is changing, but width is full screen. I have seen with firebug that the div which contains the banner is changing it's height, width when zooming. And the banner image is also shrinking.
Can anyone help me doing this thing?

Comment: Use Flexslider (Google search will get you what u want)

Comment: Actually I have tried the CSS3 feature. There is a div with 100% width which contains the image. I have been using: background-size:100% auto. This makes the banner image to be always 100% of width. But when I zoom out, the image is cropped. It can be seen here: http://sa.thinksimple.no/about-us.php

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers you need to support, you could use 
    `background-size: cover;`

Read more about it here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/